# Convert Char into Date

Tags: sql-server, date, char

I know it it really simple to do that with the Convert instruction BUT the thing is that I need to convert from mm/yyyy/dd into Date and I can't find the style value to do this and SQL server sends the error message that it can't convert it.

Here's my code:

```
Create table Clients
(
name char(150),
birthday char(10),
register_date char(10)
)
Go

Insert into Clientes values ('Ralph Van Beethoven', '12/1990/10', Convert(char(10), GetDate(), 103))
```

In other words, I need to Convert '12/1990/90' into Date and I'm doing this:

```
Convert(char(100), birthday)
```

Do I need a value after birthday or what do I need?
Thanks :)

Comment: Well the first response is: by what requirement are you storing dates a) as text and b) in a completely nonstandard (and to my mind, nonsensical) format?

Comment: Is a SQL Practice. I know it is really stupid the format I'm using when Iinsert the date BUT that's how my professor told me to do it :/

Actually I wasn't using that format in my birthday but my professor said that it was wrong because I didn't do it as he said.

Comment: And if you absolutely must support that format, use substring to get the dd, mm, and yyyy components separately, reassemble them in a supported order, and use convert with an appropriate (and deterministic) style.

Comment: Is the sole purpose of him having you insert it that way, to convert it later? Because that is absolutely terrible.

Comment: If you need to convert it to date, then use CONVERT(datetime, birthday) not CONVERT(char(100), birthday)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zastai for the answer.

Here's the code I used to convert it (as he said, I needed a Substring).

```
birthday = Substring(birthday,1,2) + Substring(birthday,8,3) + Substring(birthday,3,5);
```